# Echo the Count output PHP, PostGres

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

How can I get the output of this query and store it in a variable?

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT count('No_of_wins') from \"Records\" ");
$result->execute();
```

So I can echo it somewhere in the page. I used PHP, PostgreSQL and PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT count('No_of_wins') from \"Records\" ");
$count = $result->execute();

echo($count);
```